# form token not matching

Tags: php, forms, session, token

When form is submitted with $token #1 token are matching , but when submitted with $token #2 tokens dont match getting "redir"
I'm little bit confused why is this happening and not sure what I'm doing wrong here

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){

    if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']) {

          echo "login ";        
     }
     else
     {

       echo "redir " ;
     }

}

// 1st test
 // $token  = time();

// 2nd test
 $token  = md5(time().$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 $_SESSION['token'] = $token;

?>                       





      <form action="" method="post">

     <input type="hidden" name="token" value=" <?php echo $token ?> ">
     <input type="text" name="usr">
     <input type="text" name="pass">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">



</form>







 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: sidenote: just making sure that both `1)` and `2)` aren't part of your real code; are they?

Comment: no they are not

Comment: Ok, I made a slight edit to it; see the answer below then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try removing the spaces between the quoting and the token echo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value=" <?php echo $token ?> ">
```

try

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token ?>">
```

also, you may be getting through the first time because _SESSION token is empty.  let's be sure to test for that, too:

```
if (! empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
```